# Google microformats & itemscope Tag

Tags: seo, microformats

Google recommends using the attribute itemscope with div tags and span tags.
Can they be used with HTML 5 section tag without trouble ?

```
<section id="product" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Product">
....
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. [The specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/microdata.html) explicitly use the `<section>` tags in an example. They also use other tags besides `<div>` and `<span>` as well.

```
<section itemscope itemtype="http://example.org/animals#cat">
 <h1 itemprop="name">Hedral</h1>
 <p itemprop="desc">Hedral is a male american domestic
 shorthair, with a fluffy black fur with white paws and belly.</p>
 <img itemprop="img" src="hedral.jpeg" alt="" title="Hedral, age 18 months">
</section>
```